# Job search filter by companies that use the built-in application process

Tags: feature-request, jobs

**Feature Request:**

It would be useful to filter the job listings by those companies that use the internal SO Careers application process. Or if not a filter, an icon or indicator on the listing results.

**Background:**

- I love the Careers Profile approach that tries to pull together lots of areas (e.g. Top Answers, Open Source, Books Read) to let a potential employer get a more complete impression than typically gleaned from only cover letter and resume.
- Apparently companies that post jobs to the site have a radio button about whether they're going to use the built-in application process or simply provide a link to other site for actually submitting resume.
- I'm going to take a wild guess and assume that in most cases when companies **don't** use the built-in application process that they also haven't adopted the philosophy of using the Careers Profile to get a sense of the candidate.
- In Careers Profile you need to say whether you're an active or passive candidate, but in the real world this is more of a continuum where you might sometimes apply to job listings that look interesting.
- In this "somewhere between passive and active" job search mode, I would prefer to pursue employers who have "bought into" the philosophy of the site and are not just using it as one more source to collect a giant pile of resumes and sift them later.

Answer (score 2):

The primary reason some employers do not use our native application process is not because they haven't bought into our philosophy of what matters when evaluating a candidate, but because they use external applicant tracking systems that help them track all of their open positions and not just developer positions.

These external ATS' are difficult for us to integrate with, because most of them do not have API's that we can write and create a candidate record to.  The hiring company has to make the decision to fracture their tracking efforts between developers and everything else, or just use a different external link on Careers to keep everything in the same place.

We're talking to the large ATS companies about how to integrate, but it's a slow process.  Now with all this being said, it's not unreasonable to only want to apply to companies with your Careers profile, and to have a way to search for those companies that will allow it.  We'll look into it.